# Search folder, find and copy files to new folder corresponding file ending

Tags: command-line, bash

I have manage to grab some data of a couple of hdd with photorec, but I can't figure out how the files are saved, and it not very convenient searching in those `recup_dir.*`. So my thought is to categorize by file endings. So all *.gif end up in `/home/mike/photorec/12gb/sorted/gif` or something like that. But I don't know how to search the root catalog, grab the file extension and move/cp to that folder (and if not present, create the folder).

This way I can just delete unnecessary folders/files like `dll`.

Lets say I have three folders:

```
~/photorec/80gb
~/photorec/120gb
~/photorec/100gb
```

Photorec creates a large amount of folder naming `recup_dir.1`, `recup_dir.2` etc. like:

```
.
├── recup_dir.1
├── recup_dir.10
├── recup_dir.11
├── recup_dir.12
└── recup_dir.9
    ├── f21750248.jpg
    ├── f21750275.gif
    ├── f21750277.gif
    ├── f21750281.gif
    ├── f21750296.jpg
```

I want to `cd 80gb`, run a command or execute a bash script inside `~/photorec/80gb/` so that a new folder is created, `sorted`, and inside sorted I get all files from `recup_dirs`, sorted by the found files extensions.

```
.
├── recup_dir.1
├── recup_dir.10
├── recup_dir.11
├── recup_dir.12
├── sorted
    ├── gif
        ├── f21750275.gif
        ├── f21750277.gif
        ├── f21750281.gif
    ├── jpg
        ├── f21750248.jpg
        ├── f21750296.jpg
```

How can I achieve this?

Edit: This is not just photorec. It could be any folder ofc.

Answer (score 4):

First, create some test files:

```
mkdir -p 80gb/recup_dir.{1,10,11,12,9}
touch 80gb/recup_dir.9/f00{1..3}.{jpg,png,gif}
```

This gives:

```
.
└── 80gb
    ├── recup_dir.1
    ├── recup_dir.10
    ├── recup_dir.11
    ├── recup_dir.12
    └── recup_dir.9
        ├── f001.gif
        ├── f001.jpg
        ├── f001.png
        ├── f002.gif
        ├── f002.jpg
        ├── f002.png
        ├── f003.gif
        ├── f003.jpg
        └── f003.png
```

Now:

```
find 80gb -type f -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p sorted/"${0##*.}"; mv "$0" sorted/"${0##*.}"' {} \;
```

`$0` holds the current filename (the `{}` parameter to the *scriptlet*) and
`"${0##*.}"` is the file's extension.

Result:

```
.
├── 80gb
│   ├── recup_dir.1
│   ├── recup_dir.10
│   ├── recup_dir.11
│   ├── recup_dir.12
│   └── recup_dir.9
└── sorted
    ├── gif
    │   ├── f001.gif
    │   ├── f002.gif
    │   └── f003.gif
    ├── jpg
    │   ├── f001.jpg
    │   ├── f002.jpg
    │   └── f003.jpg
    └── png
        ├── f001.png
        ├── f002.png
        └── f003.png
```

If you want the `sorted` directory below `80gb` it might
be easiest to do a `cd 80gb` first and then do `find . …`
instead of `find 80gb …`.

Instead of `mv` you may first want to do `cp` instead
in case anything goes wrong.

### Caveat

The expression `"${0##*.}"` only works for files *with an extension*.
For files without an extension it returns the complete filename (including the path)
and the command will fail. If you expect files without extensions modify the command
to:

```
find 80gb -type f -name "*.*" -exec … \;
```

so it catches only files with a dot in them.

Comment: Another way  to test is to prepend `echo` to the `mv` command, so that you see what command would be executed

Comment: How about testing whether the dir exists and only call the external (!) `mkdir` if not? `[ -d sorted/"${0##*.}" ] || mkdir …`

Comment: Yes, @dessert, that's better if speed matters – which I doubt in this particular case. I was lazy and wanted to avoid an overly long command with multiple ugly expressions in it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a way which moves all files of one extension at once by using `bash`’s `globstar` option and looping over the different extensions:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in $(find -type f -name "*.*" -printf '%p\n' | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort -u); do \
  mkdir -p sorted/"$i"; \
  mv **/*."$i" sorted/"$i"; \
done
```

The `find | sed | sort` command list creates a list of existing file extensions over which the `for` loop loops. For every extension, `mkdir` creates a directory under `sorted/` and `m`o`v`es the matching files to it. `**/` is the globstar pattern and matches (theoretically) infinite directories and subdirectories, see [`man bash`/SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands) under shopt/globstar.

#### Example run

```
$ mkdir -p 80gb/recup_dir.{1,10,11,12,9}
$ touch 80gb/recup_dir.9/f00{1..3}.{jpg,png,gif}
$ tree
.
└── 80gb
    ├── recup_dir.1
    ├── recup_dir.10
    ├── recup_dir.11
    ├── recup_dir.12
    └── recup_dir.9
        ├── f001.gif
        ├── f001.jpg
        ├── f001.png
        ├── f002.gif
        ├── f002.jpg
        ├── f002.png
        ├── f003.gif
        ├── f003.jpg
        └── f003.png
$ shopt -s globstar; for i in $(find -type f -name "*.*" -printf '%p\n' | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort -u); do mkdir -p sorted/"$i"; mv **/*."$i" sorted/"$i"; done
$ tree
.
├── 80gb
│   ├── recup_dir.1
│   ├── recup_dir.10
│   ├── recup_dir.11
│   ├── recup_dir.12
│   └── recup_dir.9
└── sorted
    ├── gif
    │   ├── f001.gif
    │   ├── f002.gif
    │   └── f003.gif
    ├── jpg
    │   ├── f001.jpg
    │   ├── f002.jpg
    │   └── f003.jpg
    └── png
        ├── f001.png
        ├── f002.png
        └── f003.png
```

Comment: Nice. Especially that you search `*.*`, i.e. just files _with_ an extension. My solution fails for files which don't have one (the `${0##*.}` is wrong then).

Comment: Done. I didn't add a "real" workaround, just a way to omit those extensionless files.

Comment: @PerlDuck Nicely done! :)