# Rename multiple files of different name and extensions with parent directory name

Tags: rename, mv

I'm trying to figure out how to rename multiple files (100s) that have different extensions to their respective sub directory name. Here is the structure:

```
Parentdir
  |--subdir1 
    |---name1.txt
    |---name2.jpeg
    |--name3.ovc
  |--subdir2
    |--name4.txt
    |--name5.tiff
    |-name6.mpeg
```

what I would like to do is batch process a rename of all files within their respective subdir name while maintaining their extension.

From the parent directory I was using this command but I'm having issues with the file extensions:

```
for subdir in *; do mv $subdir/*  $subdir.mpeg; done;
```

Comment: What is the _"respective subdir"_? Just the extension, like `txt`, `jpeg`, `ovc`, etc? In other words: what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search folder, find and copy files to new folder corresponding file ending](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102279/search-folder-find-and-copy-files-to-new-folder-corresponding-file-ending)

Comment: Your question is unclear. It would be helpful if you could add an example of old + new filename, or show example of new structure ( i.e. , edited example of what you have as structure in the question )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conjured this script that can help to achieve what you want:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

for i in "$1"/*/*
do
    old="${i##*/}"
    ext="${i##*.}"
    name=$(basename "${i%/*}")
    [ ! -d "$i" ] && [ ! -f "$1/$name/$name.$ext" ] && mv "$1/$name/$old" "$1/$name/$name.$ext"

done
```

Test:

```
parentdir
├── subdir1
│   ├── name1.ovc
│   └── name1.txt
└── subdir2
    ├── name2.ovc
    └── name2.txt
```

Results:

```
parentdir
├── subdir1
│   ├── subdir1.ovc
│   └── subdir1.txt
└── subdir2
    ├── subdir2.ovc
    └── subdir2.txt
```

Usage: `./script.sh Parentdir`

Information:

- `old="${i##*/}"`: returns filename to change (name1.ovc)
- `ext="${i##*.}"`: returns file extension (mpeg, txt)
- `name=$(basename "${i%/*}")`: returns immediate parent directory of target
  file (subdir1)
- `[ ! -d "$i" ]`: check if not a directory
- `[ ! -f "$1/$name/$name.$ext" ]`: Check if the file already exists and has been renamed already

Comment: Hi George, thanks again and I have one more question. I ran the script and sometimes the file already has the same name as the directory it is in. I get a 'same name' message and the script stops. How can I modify to skip the file and move on to the next one?